# Where do the non-static variables declared in a static block of a class in Java get stored?

Tags: java

Where do the non-static variables declared in a static block of a class in Java get stored? Logically it seems that they must be stored on the heap - even if they are primitive variables. Is it correct? If not where do they get stored?

[Edit:]
Consider this code:

```
import java.io.*;
class book
{
    static 
    {
        int a = 1; // Where does this variable get stored?
        pen p = new pen(); // Where does this reference get stored?
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
class pen
{
    public int p;    
    public pen()
    {
        System.out.println("A pen has been created!");
    }
}
class GFG 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        book b = new book();
    }
}
```

My question is, in the above code where do the variables **a** and **p** get stored? Do they get stored on the heap or on the stack?

Since the static block isn't the body of any function, I think the variables should get stored on the heap. I wanted to know if I am right or wrong.

Comment: Please provide a compilable example of your case.

Comment: Why should they be stored on the heap? There isn't even an object yet.

Comment: Do you mean local variables used in a static block? These are stored on the stack the same way as local variables used in a method.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Memory is used for static memory allocation , It will have primitive values that are specific to a method and references to objects that are in a heap, referred from the method. Everything in static block will be stored on Stack

Comment: I don't think that is properly correct. Static methods and blocks are stored in Metaspace, which is a special area of the heap, you cannot talk about stack memory there. I suppose that local non-static variable will be also stored in the Metaspace, you cannot access it as its scope starts and finishes within that block

Comment: That was a very interesting question and I don't think that should have been closed.

Comment: @MarcoTizzano thank you! Just to clarify my understanding, do the local non-static variables of the static methods too get stored on the heap (i.e. on the metaspace), or do they get stored on the stack like every other method or function?

Comment: as I said, static block are stored in Metaspace, there is no stack which is created for it. Everything which is in the static block will be in that spacial heap area, as well as local non-static varable you define in there.